# Updating path of data in Firestore after app is released

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As I plan for how to structure my data in Firestore to optimize for my use-case, I can't help but wonder what would happen if in the future I need to update the path of my data in Firestore?

Will I need to implement some mechanism of notifying all older versions of my mobile app to stop starting and require upgrades? Or a safety check when the app starts that reads a location in Firestore to decide whether the client needs to upgrade or can continue using the current version?

It seems like paths to data are supposed to be hardcoded in the client code, which can pose risk, especially for improvements in the product when data structure in Firestore is complicated (subcollections, etc)

Is there a way to better plan for this kind of a disaster in Firestore?

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/B_5o40x0Lks

Answer (score 1):

The first goal should be to make any database changes backwards compatible. It's possible a lot more often than you may think now.

But if you really want to prepare for incompatible changes you should include a version number in your database. In Cloud Firestore you'd typically put that in a global collection in a known document name, such as `/Globals/VersionNumber`. Note that this is the version number of the data model, not necessarily the version number of the app.

Now when the app starts, it reads that document first and checks if the version number matches with what it was made for. If it doesn't, tell the user to upgrade. Otherwise continue as usual.